# how to resolve error in php during excel file upload

Tags: php, php4

I am getting error The filename C:\xampp\tmp\php308F.tmp is not readable. 
How to resolve this issue? . why this error is coming?.
    App::import('Vendor','excel_reader2');

```
public function upload(){
if($this->request->is('post')){
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($_FILES['fileexcel']['tmp_name']);
$row_data = $data->rowcount($sheet_index=0);

$row = 0;
$gagal = 0;

for ($i=2; $i<=$row_data; $i++)
{
  $data1 = $data->val($i,1); 
  $data2 = $data->val($i,2);
  $data3 = $data->val($i,3);
  $data4 = $data->val($i,4);
  $data5 = $data->val($i,5);
  $data6 = '0';
  $data7 = '0'; 
  $data8 = '0';
  $data9 = '0';   

$res=$this->Item->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Item.item_name' => $data1)));
if(count($res) == '0'){
     $rs                                           = $this->Item->find('first', array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'Max(Item.no) as no'
                )
            ));
            $max                                          = $rs['0']['no'];
            $maxnumber                                    = $max + 1;
           $barcode                                  = rand('1111111', '9999999') . str_pad($maxnumber, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$obj= new GetDate();
 $date_enter=$obj->getdate();

$this->Item->query("Insert into item (item_name,item_brand,item_price,item_tax,item_quantity,date_enter,item_barcode,BLR,MUM,WEB,EXB,no) values('$data1','$data2','$data3','$data4','$data5','$date_enter','$barcode','$data6','$data7','$data8','$data9','$maxnumber')");

}
}
$this->redirect(array('Controller' => 'Item' , 'action' => 'index'));
}
}
```

Comment: can you show us the code??

Comment: Without seeing the code, seems like a file permissions problem.

Comment: why i am getting an error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your file extension? is this xls or xlsx. Check if these extensions are supported by class you are using to read excel file.